# How to Display Data from MultipleChoiceField that renders in Unicode

Tags: python, django, unicode, django-templates

I have model data that came from a MultipleChoiceField. I have figured out it is rendering in unicode, but can't figure out how to display the data.

```
{{chef.meal}} displays [u'Brunch']
```

How do you remove the unicode to only display the data?

Thanks!

Comment: How in your view is chef.meal being defined? Show us teh codez!

Comment: The problem was I was using   meal = forms.MultipleChoiceField() instead of   meal = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField() .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a list. [Join it](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#join) or [iterate over it](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for) to get the contents.

```
{{ chef.meal|join:", " }}
```

Comment: Hmm seemed to return [, u, ', B, r, u, n, c, h, ', ]

Comment: @Emile: Then something is screwing up earlier and turning into a string, which is wrong.

Comment: One last question- the problem was I was using forms.MultipleChoiceField instead of forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField which had each choice as a string. Now {{forms.meals}} shows Meal Object instead of the strings which were there. How do you iterate over this internal list of objects to display the name? I tried a {% for %} but that didn't work. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @Emile: Define the `__unicode__()` method on the model class appropriately.